# Django data types vs. MySQL types

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqldatatypes

I'm new in Django. It is possible to compare Django data types to MySQL types?
I have for example this, and I want to create a table with it's arguments (usin MySQL commands). It should be possible to work with the database using Django.

```
class Produkt(models.Model):
    je_aktivny = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    nazov = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', db_index=True)
    popis = models.TextField(default='')
    popis_kratky = models.TextField(default='')
```

So I know, that the table will be 'Produkt'.
But what columns are equal to this attributes? I want to make a table which would be equal to class Produkt. Is it possible?

My try is:
CREATE TABLE Produkt(je_aktivny TINYINT, nazov CHAR(255), popis TEXTFIELD, popis_kratky TEXTFIELD)

But I'm not sure. Will you give me an advice?

Comment: `python manage.py sqall Produkt` show you sql commands which creates table. But `python manage.py syncdb` is for creating db :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to know this. The whole point of creating a model first is that you can then automatically create the table by running `manage.py syncdb`.

Comment: Thanks, where should I put this class/es? Into manage.py file, or to my new file? Thank you

Comment: What classes? Sounds like you really need to do the tutorial.

Comment: I mean the Class Produkt, where should be the code. Yes, I've read some tutorials... but no effect :)

Comment: Models go in the models.py file. As Daniel suggested, you should do more tutorials. :)